# How to get calculated values result and add new row

Tags: angularjs

i have three  inputs , am subtracting values in two inputs and binding result in result input . but i want to add new row on button click, i tried giving ng repeat in tr but not working

```
var ReceiptsApp = angular.module('ReceiptsApp', []);

ReceiptsApp.controller('ReceiptsController', function ($scope) {
 $scope.rvm = [{}];
   $scope.addRow1 = function (index) {
        //alert('ss');
       $scope.result = $scope.r.val1 - $scope.r.val2;
        if ($scope.rvm.length == (index + 1)) {
            $scope.rvm.push({
            });
        }

    }


});
```

find code  here

```
 https://jsbin.com/qutuyodite/edit?html,js,output
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ReceiptsApp.controller('ReceiptsController', function ($scope) {
 $scope.rvm = [{}];
   $scope.addRow1 = function (index, r) {
        // pass the particular array object on which you want to perform calculations when the function is called from ng-click and access those particular objects values using r.val1 and r.val2
        //Access particular "rvm" object using index
        $scope.rvm[index].result = r.val1 - r.val2;
        if ($scope.rvm.length == (index + 1)) {
            $scope.rvm.push({
            });
        }

    }
```

In HTML

```
<td>
   <input type="text" lass="input-large" ng-model="r.result" name="res" />
  </td>
 <td>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addRow1($index, r)">Add</button>
 </td>
```

Working [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/muvafebaju/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Did this answer your question or are you facing any issues?

Comment: Thank you ravi,in my requirement i have add button out side of ng repeat and code here   https://jsbin.com/repanijitu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: You are saying you want to have only `one` add button?

Comment: actually i have that calculations(two inputs )in model popup , if i add i want to show result in table grid by closing popup   https://jsbin.com/pugoxohile/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Can you exactly describe how user will interact between popup and table?

Comment: i have 3 columns in my table grid
input(result) and two buttons . 
one is pendings ,if i click this am showing modal popup(bootstrap) in that i have that two inputs and Add button
if i click Add am closing popup and want to those calculated result in this result input in main grid
second button is for adding new row

Comment: When you click on `pendings` button `push` a new `object` into main array. Then pass that newly created object to `modal` and `bind` properties in new `object` to input fields in modal. If you do this whatever user inputs  in the modal will automatically bind to the new object(since, in JS object is a reference type). Then once you close  the the modal you can get values from the object. Use index to keep track of object.

Comment: .Am getting data ravi but when i add row that same result binding in second row also

Comment: In my answer in html I did a change.. did you make that change in your code? `ng-model="r.result"`. Notice `r.result`, which means I am pointing `result` property to a particular `r` object.

Comment: can you please go for this link and get result, if i get this my application also works  https://jsbin.com/bayisocapa/edit?html,js,output

Comment: In your app don't you have `add` button inside the table which is inside `ng-repeat`. Your table rows should be inside the `ng-repeat` right? While input fields inside modal is not in `ng-repeat`..